# using google cloud function am unable to call pandas dataframe which is stored in google cloud shell path

Tags: python, dataframe, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have simple python script that has to read data from the path which i specified in google cloud shell. when i try to run the script from shell it was working but same script and folder path if i kept in google cloud function to run as a scheduler job. am getting below error

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def read_dataframe_from_gcs(request):
# Check if the file exists in /tmp directory
   file_path = '/tmp/excel_files'
   if not os.path.exists(file_path):
       return "File not found in /tmp directory."

# Read the DataFrame from the file
   try:
       df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    # Now you have the DataFrame 'df', and you can process or use it as needed
       print(df)
       return "DataFrame successfully read from /tmp directory."

   except Exception as e:
      return f"Error while reading DataFrame: {str(e)}"
```

Error:
file_path = '/tmp/excel_files' FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/excel_files'

Comment: You forgot to include the error messages. Your question is confusing. Why do you expect Cloud Functions to be able to access files in your Cloud Shell instance? That is not supported nor easily achieved.

Comment: @JohnHanley : oh my bad forgive.. updated error as well

Comment: @JohnHanley : i don't have prior knowledge but if i run script from cloud shell and path belongs to same cloud shell it is working... but how to create scheduler job for same script? can you help which path i should store this data ?

Comment: You would specify the local path to the file inside your Cloud Function. You would either need to download the file from Cloud Storage or similar or include the file when you deploy the function.